# Connection between properties of a ring and its quotient rings

Tags: ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra, jacobian, automorphism-group

Let $R$ be a $k$-algebra, $k$ a field, and $0\neq I \neq R$ a two-sided ideal of $R$.

Denote by P a property of rings.
One says that $R$ is 'just P', if $R$ does not satisfy property P but $R/I$ satisfies property P.

**Example:** P= finite dimensional over $k$, see, for example, [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.08774) paper.

> What is known about P= every injective $k$-algebra endomorphism is surjective, hence bijective.
>   In other words, P= every monomorphism is an epimorphism, hence an automorphism.

In particular, I wonder if this may be helpful for the Dixmier Conjecture, namely, $R$ is the first Weyl algebra over $k=\mathbb{C}$.
In this case, $R$ is simple, so every endomorphism is a monomorphism. What can be said about the quotient rings of $R$?

> Truly, I first thought about the following situation: $R=\mathbb{C}[x,y]$. Assume that $p,q \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ satisfy $\operatorname{Jac}(p,q)=1$. 
>   I wonder if it may be interesting to consider $I$ such that $p,q \notin I$ (I guess that further restrictions are required, except for the obvious one $\bar{p} \neq \bar{0}, \bar{q} \neq \bar{0}$).

First we should ask when $\frac{\mathbb{C}[x,y]}{I} = \mathbb{C}[\bar{p},\bar{q}]$? if this happens then $x+I,y+I \in \mathbb{C}[\bar{p},\bar{q}]$. Then $x+I=u(\bar{p},\bar{q})=u(p,q)+I$ and $y+I=u(p,q)+I$,
for some $u,v \in \mathbb{C}[s,t]$. Therefore, $x-u(p,q) \in I$ and $y-v(p,q) \in I$.
Perhaps this is relevant somehow to the Jacobian Conjecture, I do not know yet; maybe another special case can be obtained for the JC
(taking just one ideal $I$ does not help much, for example $I=(x-p,y-q)$).

Thank you very much!

Comment: As you say, $R$ is simple, so it has no nontrivial quotient rings.

Comment: Oh, thank you.. so this is not relevant for the first Weyl algebra. Truly, I first had in mind  $R=\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ and the Jacobian Conjecture. I will soon add this (the property P is slightly different and involves the Jacobian).

Comment: You should clarify at the beginning: The nomenclature that matches the paper you quote is is that $R$ is "just P" if $R$ has the property P, but **all** $R/I$ for proper $I$ do not have that property. (That is, you got it wrong about which one has the property and which don't, and, mor importantly, there is an important "for all" quantor missing.)

Comment: That being said, I think the question in that generality is far too broad. I would suggest to restrict to the situation you are interested in, and there write down exactly what the property P is you want to investigate.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, thank you very much for your comments; you are right about the nomenclature (I was confused yesterday).

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, I wanted to ask if something is known about 'just non-automorphism'  algebras, and then try to apply the known results to my case. (Probably, we will have to concentrate on a specific subset of all ideals $\neq 0,R$).